# Retrofit HTTPBasicAuthentication

Tags: java, rest, spring-data, retrofit2, basic-authentication

How do I pass the username and password in [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) This is how I am currently doing it and it isn't working (I have a null result):

```
@Headers("Authorization: Basic user:password")
@GET("EleRepository/{ele}")
  Call<Integer> getTotal(@Path("ele") Integer ele);
```

Comment: Firstly, you should understand [how basic auth is working](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617). The value you put in the header is wrong. It's plaintext username and password for authencation, encode it with base64 instead. Also I see there is an [OkHttp interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) example in the Retrofit wiki page. Use that to do authentication for every request if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Passing password as plain text in headers is a wrong idea. This [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit) may help you to get pass this.